# Why its not necesary to check if a #temp table exist inside a store procedure in Sybase

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-iq

normally before to build a temp table(or table) I check if it exist like that:

```
  if not exists
   (select 1 from systable key join syscolumn key join  sysuser where lower(table_name) = '#mytable')
  then
  create table #mytable
    ( id bigint null)
  end if;
```

if I dont check if the table exist and I try to create a table two times with a  name that a already exist,  I recive a error messaje

The problem here its that when I try the code inside a procedure without check if the temp table exists.
I ran the procedure 2 times ( so the second time should tell me that the table already exists) but it worked perfectly

example:

```
 -- first time 
  create table #mytable
    ( id bigint null);   --  ok 
   -- second time 
  create table #mytable
    ( id bigint null);   --  error table already exist  
 --Proc
 create procedure user.create_temp_table  ()
  begin
   create table #mytable
    ( id bigint null);
  end ;
  create_temp_table  -- ok 
  create_temp_table  -- ok
```

Does anyone knows why? why i don't need to check if a temp table exist inside a procedure ?

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)

Comment: FYI, for SQL Server... There are two types of temporary tables: local and global. Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server. Not sure if this would apply here as well.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i knew , but it doesnt explain why with the same client , if i run the proc two times i dont recive a error , and the proc create the tame table 2 times (i dont disconnect the client)

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure?

Comment: hi @WEI_DBA  , I posted the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Sybase ASE ...  you can have only one #temp table (of a given name) at a given nesting/scope level.

At the connection level (eg, `isql` command prompt) you're at nesting/scope level 0.  You can create a single instance of your #temp table here.

When you call a stored proc (or fire a trigger), you step down into a new nesting/scope level.  You can create another instance of your #temp table at each new nesting/scope level.

NOTE: Keep in mind that when you exit the stored proc two key operations are performed ... 1) any #temp tables created by the proc are automatically dropped and 2) you exit the proc's nesting/scope level, ie, the nesting/scope level is decremented by one.

Consider the following example:

```
create proc child_proc
as
create table #t1(a int, b int)
select 'child_proc',name from tempdb..sysobjects where name like '#t1%' order by name
go

create proc parent_proc
as
create table #t1(a int, b int)
select 'parent_proc',name from tempdb..sysobjects where name like '#t1%' order by name
exec child_proc
go

create table #t1(a int, b int)
select 'top_level',name from tempdb..sysobjects where name like '#t1%' order by name
exec parent_proc
go

             name                 
 ----------  --------------------
 top_level   #t100000140011582650  -- command prompt

             name                 
 ----------  --------------------
 parent_proc #t100000140011582650  -- command prompt
 parent_proc #t101000140011582650  -- parent_proc

            name                 
 ---------- --------------------
 child_proc #t100000140011582650   -- command prompt
 child_proc #t101000140011582650   -- parent_proc
 child_proc #t102000140011582650   -- child_proc
```

A temp table name's format looks something like:

```
table-name + 17-byte suffix consisting of:    

     2-digit (0-padded) nesting/scope level
     5-digit (0-padded) spid
    10-digit (0-padded) number
```

For the above example my spid=14; the only difference in actual #temp table names (as seen by the system) is the nesting/scope level, which can be seen in the 4th/5th positions of the names:

```
#t1 00 00014 0011582650  -- command prompt; nesting/scope level 0
#t1 01 00014 0011582650  -- parent_proc;    nesting/scope level 1
#t1 02 00014 0011582650  -- child_proc;     nesting/scope level 2
```

Comment: thanks for your explication  but if you see my  example that i did, the temp table ist build two times in the same nesty level .. the same temp table is build inside the procedure

Comment: each time you call the stored proc you: a) step down into level 1, 2) create the temp table, 3) the temp table is dropped as you exit the stored procedure, and 4) return to level 0; so, in your example of 2 successive proc calls ... level 0 => call proc => level 1 => create #mytable => exit proc (drop #mytable) => level 0 => call proc => level 1 => create #mytable => exit proc (drop #mytable) => level 0

Comment: thanks!! I think that answer would be usefull in the given answer. Best regards !

Comment: added a note to the answer re: what happens when you exit the proc